# preg_match get text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have [test.php](http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/sop/test.php)  and on [test1.php](http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/sop/test1.php) i have this php code running

```
<?php 
$Text=file_get_contents("http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/sop/test.php");
 preg_match_all('~fid="(.*?)"~si',$Text,$Match);
 $fid=$Match[1][1];
 echo $fid;
?>
```

what i want to do is to get the text from  test.php

from this fid='gty5etrf' JavaScript an i need just the content of fid

```
<script type='text/javascript'>fid='gty5etrf'; v_width=620; v_height=490;</script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.reyhq.com/player.js'></script>
```

in the test1.php i need to show only the content

```
gty5etrf
```

what i have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 preg_match_all('/fid=\'([^\']+)\'/',$Text,$Match);
```

Your regex was wrong.
First, you were looking for `fid="..."` instead of `fid='...'`.
Second, with `.*`, the regex would match any character further than the end of the `fid` attribute.

Here is the full code :

```
preg_match_all('/fid=\'([^\']+)\'/',$Text,$Match);
$fid=$Match[1][0];
echo $fid;
```

Comment: He was using `.*?`, not `.*`. The `?` makes it non-greedy.

Comment: I don't see the difference between `.*` and `.*?` in this case.

Comment: If the input is `fid='foo' other='bar'`, `'.*'` will match `'foo' other='bar'` because it's greedy, but `'.*?'` will match only `'foo'` because it's non-greedy.

Comment: No because i'm using `[^\']` so the regex won't read further than the first `'` encountered. @PortaltvRomania : I've tried it, and it worked for me ...

Answer (score 2):

you could try the expression `fid\=\'([^\']+)\'` as the `[^\']+` makes the expression non-greedy in the correct way, also, the expression was wrong as it was looking for double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: `.*?` is already non-greedy, that's what the `?` modifier is for.

Answer (score 0):

And this should be

```
$fid=$Match[1][0];
```

instead of :

```
$fid=$Match[1][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Matching string inside `''`: `'(?:[^\\']*|\\.)*'`

Matching string inside `""`: `"(?:[^\\"]*|\\.)*"`

Both of them (ignoring spaces): `fid\s*=\s*('(?:[^\\']*|\\.)*'|"(?:[^\\"]*|\\.)*")`

And escaped for php:

```
$regexp = '~fid\\s*=\\s*(\'(?:[^\\\\\']*|\\\\.)*\'|"(?:[^\\\\"]*|\\\\.)*")~';
```

This will handle correctly even this:

```
fid  = 'foo\'s bar';
```

Answer (score 0):

a short pattern:

```
$pattern = '~\bfid\s*=\s*["\']\K\w+~';
```

or a long pattern:

```
$pattern = '~<script[^>]*>(?:[^f<]+|\Bf+|f(?!id\b)|<+(?!/script>))*+\bfid\s*=\s*(["\'])\K[^"\']+(?=\1)~';
```

the result with

```
preg_match($pattern, $Text, $match);
$fid = $match[0];
```

The short pattern finds sequences like:

```
fid='somechars
fid  = "somecchars
```

The long pattern does the same but also checks you are between script tags.

---

Using XPath:

```
$html = <<<'EOD'
<script type='text/javascript'>fid='gty5etrf'; v_width=620; v_height=490;</script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.reyhq.com/player.js'></script>
EOD;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$query = <<<'EOD'
    substring-before(
        substring-after(
            //script[contains(., "fid='")],
            "fid='"
        ),
        "'"
    )
EOD;

echo $xp->evaluate($query);
```